# Mapbox can't get last location (Java)

Tags: java, android, location, mapbox, mapbox-android

I use mapbox for android (java), when it tries to access the device location it gives me an error and closes the application. This problem does not occur when I try to use the app by simulating it.

It seems that this code doesn't work.

```
private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
    if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
        locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
        LocationComponentActivationOptions locationComponentActivationOptions =
                LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(this, loadedMapStyle)
                        .useDefaultLocationEngine(false)
                        .build();
        locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(locationComponentActivationOptions);
        locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);
        locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
        locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.COMPASS);

        initLocationEngine();
    } else {
        permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
        permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What is the crash message in the logcat?

Are you passing a fully loaded map style through to `enableLocationComponent()`?

You might have already seen them, but fyi about https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-location-listening/ and https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/#device-location